# Change default gradle settings (distributionUrl) when creating new Flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle

What I would like is to change the "new flutter project settings" so that the file in the file   `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, the value for `distributionUrl` is `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-milestone-2-all.zip` rather than `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`.

Creating a project in VSCode through `ctrl+shift+p`, `Flutter: New Project`.

Any leads on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess after creating your project the **distributionUrl** was **5.6.2** to change that to **6.8** simply modify the URL in

**./android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties: to**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip
```

and Gradle plugin.

**./android/build.gradle:** to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
```

**For the best performance, you should use the latest possible version of both Gradle and the plugin.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking to change the default setting so that I don't have to do it manually everytime

Comment: And where can you find the latest versions?